# counting when a occurs with b in files and lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sorry if this question is a bit basic, or if I've missed an answer elsewhere, but please take pity on a lost and confused beginner and give me a hand if you can.
I've got a load of long files consisting of lines of 'date time id number random crap' and I'm trying to count the amount of times certain numbers occur alongside certain ids. As far as I can tell, everything is right except I only get one number returned, rather than hundreds.
I've really cut this down to just the bits that might be going wrong. There are probably hundreds of quicker and easier ways to do what I'm trying to do, but I don't know them yet. Please do let me know!
I have a list of the data from the file, called data, and a list of the ids present in the file.

```
#get date(data[i][0]), time(data[i][1]), number(data[i][3]), id(data[i][4]) from original data if a certain id (found in listofids) is present, and write into new list
data0=[]
data1=[]
etc
values=[data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][3], data[i][4]]
for line in data:
    if listofids[0] in line:
        data0.append(values)
    if listofids[1] in line:
        data1.append(values)
    etc

#put number into list h if it occurs in list data0
h=[]
r=range (0, len(data0))
for i in r:
    number=data0[i][3]
    if number not in h:
        h.append(number)
print (len(h))
print (h)

#count the time each element in list h occurs in list data0
print (data0.count(h[0]), data0.count(h[1]), data0.count(h[2]))
```

I'm sorry if this is a bit messy and confusing, and I'm especially sorry if I'm missing something really easy.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: And how would such a line look like? Do they have a fixed format, such as no spaces in the IDs?

Comment: can you post some of the data you are parsing.

Comment: They're all '07/11/2008 09:00:06 word #0F 0006E7895B word word' in the original file, although I've cut out the words to leave just '07/11/2008 9:00:06 #0F 0006E7895B'. Obviously the dates, times, ids and numbers vary on each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They're all '07/11/2008 09:00:06 word #0F 0006E7895B word word' in the original file

Parsing that fixed format should be quite simple. In the following snippet I assume you want to count combinations of (ID, number):

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Count numbers in a dictionary that defaults to zero if a key does not exist yet
counter = defaultdict(int)

with open("filename", "rU") as f:
    for line in f:
        info = line.split()
        date, time, unused, number, id = info[:5]
        counter[id, number] += 1

for (id, number), count in counter.items():
    print("The combination id=%s, number=%s occurred %d times" % (id, number, count))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly first time. I feel pretty stupid spending 3 days writing pages and pages when 13 lines did the trick. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell without a specific example of what your input looks like and what result you want from it, but [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#counter-objects) is very likely to help you. You can feed it an iterable of the things you are interested in knowing about, and it will tell you what unique values there are in there, and how many times each appears.

You say your strings are of the form: `date time id number stuff`, and you're interested in counting occurrences of dates and numbers - it sounds like you want to count the pairs of `(id, number)` and ignore the other things. That means if you can parse each string into just that tuple, you can add it to a Counter like this:

```
count = collections.Counter()
for string in file:
   tup = # parse string into `(id, number)` tuple
   count.update([count])
```

Or, more concisely:

```
count = collections.Counter(tupleify(string) for string in file)
```

`count[(id, number)]` will then, tell you how many times a particular `(id, number)` pair appeared in the file.